# Storing .dll files in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, dll, file-storage

Where can I find information on storing ".dll" files in SQL Server 2005? Is it the same as storing Binary data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362(SQL.90).aspx) or [varbinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362(SQL.90).aspx) data type you can store any binary information including dlls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just a file like a Word document or image...

Use varbinarx(max)